# YARP - do not proxy to old API selected new endpoints

Tags: ms-yarp

Im in the middle of process to rewrite endpoints from .NET Framework -> .NET6,  we are using YARP to proxy request to old API.
Here is configuration of our Map Forwarder:

```
app.MapForwarder("/{**catch-all}", app.Configuration["ProxyTo"]!).Add(static builder => ((RouteEndpointBuilder)builder).Order = int.MaxValue);
```

Traffic is proxed through new API to old API, but if there is new endpoint (.NET6) it stays in new API.

Now we want to create configuration to proxy specific endpoints to old API even if the new one exist. Just in case if the new endpoint has not been tested complete or cointins some bugs. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to map more forwarder routes but with a higher priority than the controllers this time.

```cs
string proxyTo = app.Configuration["ProxyTo"]!;

app.MapForwarder("/{**catch-all}", proxyTo).Add(static builder => ((RouteEndpointBuilder)builder).Order = int.MaxValue);

// Note the `Order = int.MinValue`
app.MapForwarder("/MyUntestedApi/{**catch-all}", proxyTo).Add(static builder => ((RouteEndpointBuilder)builder).Order = int.MinValue);
```